# If $G$ is simple, then $Z({\rm Aut}(G)) = \{1\} \iff G$ is non-abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group, simple-groups

**NOTE:** I am aware of the link at [For a Simple Group G, Z(Aut(G)) Is Trivial if and only if G is Non-Abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053193/for-a-simple-group-g-zautg-is-trivial-if-and-only-if-g-is-non-abelian) I am looking for proof verification of $G$ non-abelian $\implies Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) = \{1\}$.

Suppose $G$ is not abelian. Then as $Z(G) \trianglelefteq G$, we get $Z(G)$ must be $\{1\}$. Now, note that $G/Z(G) \cong \mathrm{Inn}(G)$ but since $Z(G) = \{1\}$, we get $G \cong{\rm Inn}(G)$.

I will claim without proof that $Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) \trianglelefteq \mathrm{Inn}(G)$. Since $G$ is simple and $G \cong \mathrm{Inn}(G)$, then $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is simple.

Thus, $Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) = \{1\}$ or $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$. If $Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) = \mathrm{Inn}(G)$, then this will mean $G$ is abelian, a contradiction. Thus, $Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G)) = \{1\}$.

Comment: How can we verify your proof when you claim something without proof? Also it's not clear. I am referring to the claim that the center of the automorphism group only consists of inner automorphisms.

Comment: Let $\tau \in Z(Aut(G)), \sigma \in Aut(G)$. Then $\tau \sigma = \sigma \tau \implies \tau = \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} \implies \tau(x) = \sigma(x) x \sigma(x)^{-1} \implies \tau \in Inn(G)$. Oh wait a minute. I see the issue: $\sigma(x)$ DEPENDS on $x$. Maybe that's my error

Comment: You need to prove that if an automorphism centralizes ${\rm Inn}(G)$ then it acts trivially on $G$.